# How to project a Vector3 onto the xz plane?

Tags: unity, vector, linear-algebra, projection, projectile

I have this code that tries to check whether a lobbed grenade will head toward a teammate:

```cs
    var heading = tmPosition - grenadePos;
    var distance = heading.magnitude;
    var normalizedDir = heading / distance;

    if (Vector3.Dot(heading, (grenadePos + grenadeVelocity)) < 1.05f && Vector3.Dot(heading, (grenadePos + grenadeVelocity)) > 0.95f)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

`tmPosition` is the position of my teammate.  The grenade can be lobbed for long distances or thrown like a baseball (with a slightly arcing trajectory) for closer range so my teacher says to project its trajectory as well as the `heading` vector on to the ground xz plane to make sure that my code above that predicts whether a particular grenade is heading towards my teammate or not.

How do I do this?  I saw the API for `Vector3.Project` and `Vector3.ProjectOnPlane` but the examples are not very good.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. It mixes apples and oranges. `heading` is an offset vector, while `(grenadePos + grenadeVelocity)` is an absolute position. That means if I move the pair of teammate and grenade objects to different parts of the scene, without changing the relative offset between them, I'll get different answers from this function, even though the true answer has not changed. I'd recommend asking a separate question about how to detect this case correctly, including a diagram to show which cases should return true and which should return false.

Comment: But wouldn't heading be calculated with different values for `tmPosition` and `grenadePos` when they get moved to different parts of the scene?

Comment: It would, but since we're moving them together, the value would still be the same. "2 to the left and 3 up" is the same offset vector, whether you're measuring from (0, 0) to (-2, 3) or from (2, -3) to (0, 0) or from (100, 100) to (98, 103). But in each of those places `grenadePos` is different, so you're comparing one vector that's always the same against one vector that keeps changing, leading to changing answers when you want the answer to stay the same.

Comment: Wait a second, then all I have to do is add the `grenadePos` to the offset vector and it would become an offset dependent on the initial `grenadePos`, different each time I believe.

Comment: Actually that sounds wrong, I'll post new question here.

Comment: @DMGregory https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/204868/135208

Comment: If you add an absolute position to a relative offset vector, you get an absolute position. That's not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 0-out the Y coordinate. This is called an orthographic projection:

```
Original vector:                    (1, 2, 3)
Ortographic projection on XZ plane: (1, 0, 3)
```