# Predict whether projectile is coming at a teammate

Tags: unity, vector, linear-algebra

Related to this question [How to project a Vector3 onto the xz plane?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/204855/135208)

```
var heading = tmPosition - grenadePos;
    var distance = heading.magnitude;
    var normalizedDir = heading / distance;

    if (Vector3.Dot(heading, (grenadePos + grenadeVelocity)) < 1.05f && Vector3.Dot(heading, (grenadePos + grenadeVelocity)) > 0.95f)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

This is apparently wrong since heading stays the same regardless of where `grenadePos` and `tmPosition` are in the scene where as the `grenadePos + grenadeVelocity` differs for each position in the scene.
How can I do this correctly so that I can predict if indeed that grenade is coming at my teammate?
My initial thought was to add `grenadePos` to the `heading` but that makes no sense as `heading = teammatePos - grenadePos`.

Comment: Is this going to be a one-time check at the time of launch, or a continuous check until the grenade explodes?

Comment: Also, do you want to check against where your teammate is, or where your teammate will be?

Comment: Remember that I'd asked you to include a diagram to indicate how you want this function to work. Right now it seems like you're not taking into account the arc of the grenade — so you don't care where the grenade is predicted to *land*, only the direction it's flying, is that right?

Comment: One way to solve this issue is to use the dot product of the normalized direction vector and the velocity vector of the grenade instead of using the dot product of the heading vector and the sum of grenade position and velocity vectors.